# How to use Html Agility Pack to pick out the specific text?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Below is an example portion of a block of the Html that I am trying to extract information from:

```
<a href="https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Alemao+Golpista" >Alemao&#160;Golpista</a></td><td style="width:10%;" >51</td><td style="width:20%;" >Knight</td></tr><tr class="Even" style="text-align:right;" ><td style="width:70%;text-align:left;" >
```

I am basically grabbing the entire Html which is a list of players online and trying to append them to a list with the: Name (Alemao Golpista), Level (51), and  Vocation (Knight).

Using regex for it is a pain in the ass and pretty slow how would I go about it using the Agility Pack?

Comment: If you want to use HTMLAgilityPack then you need to show us the entire HTML or a link to the page from where you got that snippet.

Comment: And additionally you need to read HTMLAgilityPack docs and look at examples.

Answer (score -1):

Don't ever use regex to parse html files. As has already been stated you should use whatever HtmlagilityPack examples you can find even though they are scarce on their site. And the documentation isn't easy to find.

To get you started here is how you can load an HtmlDocument and get the anchor tags' href attributes.

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

try{
    var temp = new Uri(url.Url);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(temp);
    request.Method = "GET";
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            htmlDoc.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));
        }
    }
}catch(WebException ex){
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
 }

HtmlNodeCollection c = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");

List<string> urls = new List<string>();
foreach(HtmlNode n in c){
    urls.Add(n.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
}
```

The above code gets you all the links of a webpage in a string array.
You should look into [xpath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And you should also get the [documentation](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00839011553420004828) of HAP and read it. I couldn't find the documentation anywhere, so I uploaded the one I already had on my computer.